# Show that $\mathbb{Z}[i]=\{m+in\colon\; m,n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is a P.I.D

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, principal-ideal-domains, gaussian-integers

I came across the following problem

> Show that the ring of the Gaussian integers, defined as the subring of $\mathbb{C}$ given by the set $\mathbb{Z}[i]=\{m+in\colon\; m,n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$, where $i=\sqrt{-1}$, is a principal ideal domain (P.I.D).

But can't seem to get anywhere. Clearly $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is an integral domain since $\mathbb{C}$ has no zero divisors and $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a subset of $\mathbb{C}$ which is also commutative. What I can't seem to be able to show is that every ideal on $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is principal and I don't even know where to start so I've come here looking for some *hints* on how to prove this last part.

Btw, I have never heard the term Gaussian prime before or anything regarding the Gaussian intigers.

Comment: Have you ever shown *some* integral domain is a PID?

Comment: nop lol, I've just learned the definition right before encountering the problem. Should I assume that an ideal is generated by two items and show that that ideal can be generated by only one?

Comment: Then perhaps start by proving that the integers $\mathbb{Z}$ are a principal ideal domain, and try to modify the proof to work for $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Comment: @ErikD for $\mathbb{Z}$ I used the fact that every ideal is an additive subgroup, since $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ is cyclic, so is every ideal. So every ideal happens to be of the form $\langle m \rangle$, but, in $\mathbb{Z}$, $\langle m \rangle=(m)$ and thus $\mathbb{Z}$ is an PID. The problem is that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ isn't cyclic (I think). So I wouldn't know how to use this fact.

Comment: I'll be honest: this problem you are working on (what does "came across the following problem" mean -- is it homework or something else?) can be found in many abstract algebra books and on numerous webpages.  It is one of the first instances of a PID that student learn about beyond the case of the integers.  Perhaps it would be instructive to see how this case is proved from a reference and then try to adapt the method to show $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{-2}]$ and $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{2}]$ are PIDs.

Comment: I think it is best first to show that the ring is *Euclidean* (this is an important definition), so that it is a PID.